# Explanation of MySQL query additions

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a function within my C# app that in this instance is creating a new table in a MySQL database.  However when I edit the table structure (after creation), I see three lines that were not added via the code.

Do I need to double check any of these, or should them be OK?

```
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Syntax used:

CREATE TABLE egr.`test` (
machine_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
machine_desc varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
product_family varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
factory varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
model varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
size varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (machine_id)) ENGINE = INNODB;

Comment: add the code that you are using to create the table.

Comment: Code has been updated - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the code. When you create a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
machine_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
machine_desc varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
product_family varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
factory varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
model varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
size varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (machine_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

and then use the command `show create table test`

You will get to see something as

```
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `machine_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `machine_desc` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_family` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `factory` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`machine_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Now why `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` is not shown, since if its set to 1 at the beginning then its not shown and it means that its set to 1 which is implied, however if you create the same above table as

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
machine_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
machine_desc varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
product_family varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
factory varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
model varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
size varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (machine_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 ;
```

And then `show create table test` it will display as

```
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `machine_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `machine_desc` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_family` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `factory` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`machine_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Since the primary key is not longer 1 and the table description will show you where the last id of the auto_incremented value is.

If you need to know the other details of the tables in the database you may need to use the following command as

`show table status from your_db_name \G`

And you may get something as

```
mysql> show table status from test \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 12582912
 Auto_increment: 2
    Create_time: 2014-05-23 16:39:08
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```